# Python "IF" Statement

Tags: python, if-statement

```
code_str = input("Enter code: ")

while code_str !="Q":
    print("Code:",code_str)
    if code_str == 'B' and code_str == "D" and code_str == "W":
        print("Good Code.")
    else:
        print("Bad code. Try Again")
    code_str = input("Enter code: ")
```

I need to make it so, it prints Good Code whenever B, D, or W, is inputed by the user, however I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: It should always prints "Bad code". I think

Comment: `and`? how's that going to work?

Comment: Don't edit your question to turn it into an entirely different question; ask a new one.

Answer (score 2):

if code_str is `B`, it can't possibly be `D` and `W` at the same time!

You need to change your `and` to `or`:

```
if code_str == 'B' or code_str == "D" or code_str == "W":
```

---

or to simplify a bit:

```
if code_str in ('B', 'D', 'W'):
```

---

the following simplifies even further, but will match `BD` and `DW` and `BDW` and empty strings as well. if you've already sanitized the input to be a single character it's ok though:

```
if code_str in 'BDW':
```

Comment: or to further simplify it: `in "BDW"`

Comment: No, the tuple is right. We don't want to allow `BD` as input.

Answer (score 0):

```
if code_str == 'B' and code_str == "D" and code_str == "W":
```

The condition of the above if-statement will always evaluate to `False` because `code_str` will never be both equal to `"B"` *and* equal to `"D"`.

To fix the problem, you need to use [`or`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#or) instead of `and`:

```
if code_str == 'B' or code_str == "D" or code_str == "W":
```

or, you can use [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in):

```
if code_str in ("B", "D", "W"):
```

---

**Edit:**

For your updated question, you can use [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower):

```
while code_str.lower() != "q":
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if code_str == 'B' and code_str == "D" and code_str == "W":
```

should be

```
if code_str == 'B' or code_str == 'D' or code_str == 'W':
```

or (better):

```
if code_str in {'B', 'D', 'W'}:
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `if` statement to return `True` if only one of the conditions is `True`, you can't use the `and` operator for that since it only returns `True` if all the conditions are. So, you should replace the `and` operators with the `or` operator.